# How to source an env file and then execute Python script via cronjob?

Tags: python, bash, unix, cron

I have several python apps.
To run these apps, I must 1st execute the virtual environment by issuing the following command:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

I need to run these files using a cronjob (on Unix).

How can I get the a BASH shell script to execute a python app and make it run in its virtual environment?

Thanks

Comment: Execute a bash shell script with cron that in turn runs python script after sourcing VEnv

Comment: Compile your python app with pyinstaller to onefile and run it from crontab  /path/to/pyinstaller_file